# Filtering data in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute

I am not very experienced with the ModelBuilder and am new to ArcGIS Desktop.

I want to use the ModelBuilder to select data from a polygon feature dataset in a first step. The dataset represents the population density of all the districts in a country and I want to only select those, that have a population density of 30% or above.

How can I achieve this with the ModelBuilder?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this your model will need to include two tools:

1. Make Feature Layer
2. Select Layer By Attribute

Comment: I got it now. My approach of first importing my layers and then trying to apply a tool to it, was just wrong. I just had to import the Select Layer By Attribute tool and select the layer with that.